# Proving a polynomial ring isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory

From [Leinster - Basic  Category Theory 2016](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) p8

My question is how to solve **(b) below.** In particular it was my thought that, using the homomorphism property proved in (a), the supplied definition of $\psi$ in (b) has no relevance to the solution. Would someone please tell me how am I mistaken?

Denote by $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ the polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$ in one variable.

(a) Prove that for all rings $R$ and all $r ∈ R$, there exists a unique ring homomorphism $φ: \mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow R$ such that $φ(x) = r.$

(b) Let $A$ be a ring and $a ∈ A$. Suppose that for all rings $R$ and all $r ∈ R$, there
exists a unique ring homomorphism $φ: A → R$ such that $φ(a) = r$. Prove
that there is a unique isomorphism $ι: \mathbb{Z}[x] → A$ such that $ι(x) = a.$

Thank you

Comment: dear Adam, note that Leinster is asking you to construct an *isomorphism* $\iota:\mathbb{Z}[x]\to A$ with the desired properties, not just a homomorphism. you are correct that the existence of such a homomorphism follows immediately from part (a), but proving that it is an isomorphism requires you to use the properties of $A$

Comment: Hint: write $\phi: A \rightarrow R$ and draw the diagram. This will help you to visualize how to construct such isomorphism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** This is an example of a universal property. Using part (a), you have a unique morphism from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to $A$ sending $x$ to $a;$ call this $\iota.$ To prove $\iota$ is an isomorphism, you just need to construct its inverse. By what property of $A$ can you construct a candidate map for $\iota^{-1} : A \rightarrow\mathbb{Z}[x],$ and how can you show they are inverses?

Answer (score 0):

$\iota \colon \mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow A$ maps
$\sum_{i=1}^n p_ix^i$ to $\sum_{i=1}^n p_ia^i$, using $\iota(x) = a$,
the multiplicative property of a homomorphism to get $\iota(x^i)=\iota(x)^i$,
and the additive property to get $\iota(p_i)\iota(x)^i = p_i\iota(x)^i$ remembering $p_i$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Going in the direction $A \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[x]$ we know as provided in (b) above that,
taking $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and $\psi=\iota^\prime$, there exists a unique ring homomorphism such that $\iota^\prime(a)=x$.
So $\iota^\prime $ maps $\sum_{i=1}^np_ia^i$ to $\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_ix^i$ and $\iota^\prime \circ \iota = 1_{\mathbb{Z}[x]}$.
Also using definitions of $\iota$ and $\iota^\prime$ easily yields $\iota \circ \iota^\prime = 1_A$